# Getting compilation error while building spring using gradle

Tags: spring, build, gradle

I am learning to use Spring and gradle by downloading the spring source using git. I have downloaded it using 
     git clone git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework.git
Also I have setup gradle in my local.

While I am trying to execute

gradle build

I am getting compilation error as follows:

```
C:\Users\mahendran\spring-framework>gradle build
:spring-core:asmRepackJar
:spring-core:cglibRepackJar
:spring-core:compileJava
C:\Users\mahendran\spring-framework\spring-core\src\main\java\org\springframework\util\xml\StaxUtils.java:318: 
cannot find symbol symbol : method newFactory()
location: class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory
            return new XMLEventStreamWriter(eventWriter, XMLEventFactory.newFactory());
                                                                        ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
:spring-core:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spring-core:compileJava'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 5.58 secs
```

Comment: Is your JDK installed with JAVA_HOME environmental variable? XMLEventFactory class exists in the JDK.

Comment: @UmeshRajbhandari Yes, I have installed jdk1.6.0 and the same path is set in JAVA_HOME environmental variable.

Comment: I am also not seeing XMLEventFactory.newFactory() method in j2se5 doc.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/index.html?javax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory.html

Comment: Try with `gradlew build`, not `gradle build`. No need to set up Gradle manually. If that doesn't help, show the output of `gradlew -v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like version skew - I think you need to update your JDK.  AFAICT, newFactory() was added in JDK6 version 1.6.0.18.